# getting this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get cuisines of new york city from the website: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisine_of_New_York_City

and I am getting the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

This is the code I have tried.

```
website_url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisine_of_New_York_City').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})

headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')        
rows = []
for row in table_rows:
   td = row.find_all('td')
   row = [row.text for row in td]
   rows.append(row)

with open('BON2_POPULATION1.csv', 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(headers)
   writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Comment: You are getting this error because of your `soup.find` not able to find any `table` tag with `class:wikitable sortable` property and so its returning `none`.

Comment: How can I correct this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no element with that description. As a starters for 10 you could use `:contains`, with bs4 4.7.1+, and capture the elements with class `mw-headline` that contains the word cuisine in their `innerText/text`. The list is needs a little cleaning. If you intended something more specific then more info is needed in the question.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisine_of_New_York_City')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
cuisines_dirty = [i.text for i in soup.select('.mw-headline:contains(cuisine)')]
#perform some sort of cleaning on list
```

---

**Dirty list:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You are getting this error because of your soup.find not able to find any `table` tag with `class:wikitable sortable` property and so its returning none

```
website_url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisine_of_New_York_City').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})

headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
if table is None:
    #handle something here when table is not present in your html.
else:
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')        
    rows = []
    for row in table_rows:
        td = row.find_all('td')
    row = [row.text for row in td]
    rows.append(row)

    with open('BON2_POPULATION1.csv', 'w') as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f)
       writer.writerow(headers)
       writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```